# Horizontal spacing on sum with long index

Tags: spacing

My working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\Lambda}_{a'} = \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i, j \mid b_{i} \in \mathscr{B}, c_{j} \in \mathscr{C}}} \ket{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \bra{a', b_{i}, c_{j}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

giving this output:
[image]

I would like the i in the sum's index to start underneath but alongside where the equal sign starts and the rest (Sum + Ket & Bra) to be moved left accordingly.

So far, I have tried the option [lr] in the smash operator, which moves the i a little to far left in my opinion and also encapsulation the sum's subscript in `\mathllap{}` which makes the i start right at the start of the line.

Any suggestions?

If you think my idea of how it's supposed to look is off, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you employ the `\substack` macro (provided by the `amsmath` package, which in turn is loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package) to introduce a line break in the material below `\sum`. In addition, I would use `\smashoperator`, not `\smashoperator[r]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools,braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\Lambda}_{a'} = \smashoperator{\sum_{%
  \substack{i, j \mid b_{i} \in \mathscr{B},\\ 
            c_{j} \in \mathscr{C}}}} 
  \ket{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \bra{a', b_{i}, c_{j}}
\end{equation}

% 2 tweaks: restore a bit of extra whitespace before \ket,
%           shift 2nd row of \substack to the right.
\begin{equation} 
\hat{\Lambda}_{a'} = \smashoperator{\sum_{%
  \substack{i, j \mid b_{i} \in \mathscr{B},\\ 
            \hfill c_{j} \in \mathscr{C}\phantom{,}}}} 
  \,\ket{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \bra{a', b_{i}, c_{j}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```